# Sharepoint 2007 - How can i access default.aspx (portal homepage)?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, web-parts

Ive been having a problem with a webpart in a sharepoint (moss 2007) site.

Basically I cannot remove the webpart, every which way results in an error and we cant get rid of the darn thing.

Unfortunately SharePoint designer errors out as wel when I try to remove the webpart manually from Default.aspx (its only on the homepage).

Is there anyway without SharePoint designer I can gain access to the Default.aspx file so I can manually remove the webpart?

Someone mentioned default.aspx doesnt actually exist and is generated at runtime? Is this true and if so does anyone know where in the moss database I could gain acces to the table(s) that build up the default.aspx or where the webpart refs are stored for manual removal?

Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding `?contents=1` at the end of your URL page. for example:

```
http://myserver/Pages/default.aspx?contents=1
```

this will bring you to a "Web Part Page Maintenance" page where you can checkout the page itself and remove/disable web parts.

Comment: already done that :) errors out when i try to reset, delete etc :

Comment: from the webpart maintenance page i get the following when i try to delete the webpart...    "Could not complete the operation. Cannot complete this action. Please try again. "

Comment: and when i try and delete the webpartt from the homepage i get... "Operation aborted (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004004 (E_ABORT)) "

Comment: Do you have enough space on your disk? have a look here `http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en/sharepointgeneral/thread/b3ba89ca-48f9-47dd-92e2-c77d8585ac94`

Comment: disk space is fine also, no problems with log sizes etc. do you know if you can gain access to default.aspx anywhere other than sharepoint designer? or am ibarking up the wrong tree, as i see this as i only option really, as weve tried everything and its failed.

Comment: I am not sure what to suggest you now. Maybe the better thing to do is to create another page in the site and then change the default page of the site. So you can have again the site working while you try to find a solution. I had once a problem with a broken navigation and I was not able to find any solution.... :(